# Angular forms: setting a $dirty property on a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have a directive (let say check-button) that creates a styled checkbox with some specific functionality.

I require ng-form in the directive, So I can user the formCtrl in the directive and I succeed in setting the **form** to be $dirty or $valid. **My problem** is how to set the specific element created by the directive to be $valid or $dirty and generally behave as an angular form element. just doing `element.$valid = false` doesn't work as is `fromCtrl.addControl(element)` So I'm stuck. I should stress that this directive is used inside an ng-repeat loop so I can just set a "name" on it, since ng-repeat can set a name programmtically (has to be a string)

this is the (simplfied) template:

```
<div class="check-button ">
    <div c" ng-class="{ 'active': value != undefined ? btnState == value : btnState }">
        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left btn-label" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

and this is the code:

```
angular.module('our.directives').directive('checkButton', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require:'?^form', //may be used outside a form
        templateUrl: '/tempalte/path/tpocheckbutton.html',
        scope: {
            btnState: '=ngModel',
            value: '=radioBtn'
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, formCtrl) {
            if(formCtrl){

                formCtrl.$addControl($element)//doesn't work
            }

            $scope.$watch(function() {
                return $scope.btnState;
            }, function(newValue) {
                $scope.btnState = newValue;
            });

            var _onElementClick = function() {
                if($scope.value != undefined) {
                    $scope.btnState = $scope.value;
                } else {
                    $scope.btnState = !$scope.btnState;
                }
                if(formCtrl){
//                    $element.$dirty = true;//doesn't work
                    formCtrl.$setDirty(); //does set the form as dirty - but not the field
                }

            };

            $element.find('.button, .btn-label').on('click', _onElementClick);
        }
    };
}]);
```

We are using the latest angular version (1.2.10)

Comment: you cannot add an element to a `formController`, you need to require the `ngModelController` of that element. Now, can you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to require both `form` and `ngModel` as `form.$addControl` expects an `ngModelController`.

Comment: Thanks @beyers ! and after requiring both, how do I add it? just add the modelCtrl object?

Comment: @alonisser You dont actually have to do anything to register the control as the ngModel directive itself registers with the form. So all you need is just a reference to the ngMogelController so you can use its API. For ngModelController API and example of custom control have a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController